# Why does my ASP.NET Core 7 Razor pages app return 404 with 'dotnet <appname>.dll' command?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

ASP.NET Core 7 Razor pages app returns 404 when app is running using

```
dotnet <appname>.dll
```

When I build the app using

```
dotnet build <app>.csproj --configuration Release
```

[image: build]

and then launch the app with `dotnet <app>.dll`, the app returns a http 404 error for all requests

[image: run]

However, when I launch the app using Visual Studio, or build using Visual Studio, and then run using same command, everything works.

My app is an ASP.NET Core 7 Razor pages web application.

launchSettings.json

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:18790",
      "sslPort": 44367
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess"
    },
    "<app>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

update:
resolved by adding `global.json`

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.101"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "7.0.101"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the appsettings.json and other configuration files copied to the directory you try to run it in? When you build from vs, it ensures all the necessary files are copied with it to the bin directory. It looks like it's running at a different port. See the error/ warning in the image.

Comment: @JHBonarius yes, appsettings.json is there. Also in middleware I log Request.Path and it displays route, but still returns 404 and probably doesn't trigger required Page

Comment: It also works in the same way on Azure App Service. When I publish with Visual Studio it works, when I publish with Azure DevOps pipelines (standard build, publish) it returns 404

Comment: There's outback some port configuration in you launch settings that is only used for vs build. Check those

Comment: @JHBonarius i attached launch settings to description

Comment: Indeed you did. Do you see how the compiler will get confused by that? You have a number of profiles, which are used by visual studio, and some IIS settings in the root. Things seem to be conflicting.  If you cleanup the launch settings, it should work again.

Comment: @JHBonarius launchsettings changes didn't help, but i added global.json and provided sdk version, looks like everything works now.
"sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.101"
  },